# JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT not working with custom serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsonserializer

I want to both use a custom serializer and have the `JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT` designation be honored.  When I don't use a custom serializer it is honored but when I do use a custom serializer it is not.

This is Jackson 2.2.2.  I do not presently have the option to switch to a newer version of Jackson.

Here's a simple example that shows the problem:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;    

public class JacksonSerialization
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper serializer = new ObjectMapper();

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setFlags(EnumSet.of(Flag.CC, Flag.BB));
        System.out.println(serializer.writeValueAsString(foo));

        foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(serializer.writeValueAsString(foo));
    }

    public static enum Flag
    {
        AA,
        BB,
        CC
    }

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    public static class Foo
    {
        private Set<Flag> flags;

        public Foo() {
            flags = EnumSet.of(Flag.AA);
        }

        @JsonGetter("f")
        @JsonSerialize(using = FlagSetSerializer.class)
        public Set<Flag> getFlags() {
            return flags;
        }

        public void setFlags(Set<Flag> theFlags) {
            flags = theFlags;
        }
    }

    public static class FlagSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Set<Flag>>
    {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Set<Flag> value,
                              JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            String csv = value.stream()
                    .map(Flag::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            jsonGenerator.writeString(csv);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
{"f":"BB,CC"}
{"f":"AA"}
```

Note that `f` is being serialized even when it has the default value.  If I comment out the `@JsonSerialize` annotation then I get the following output:

```
{"f":["BB","CC"]}
{}
```

Then `f` properly does *not* get serialized.  But of course things are not being serialized in the format I want.

So how do I get the custom serializer to honor the class's `@JsonInclude` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to implement `public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, T value)` as per the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html#isEmpty(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider,%20T)), which says:

> public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, T value)
>
> Method called to check whether given serializable value is considered
>   "empty" value (for purposes of suppressing serialization of empty
>   values).
>
> Default implementation will consider only null values to be
>   empty.

As per https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/730

Another possible source of trouble is that you talk about `NON_EMPTY` but you code uses `NON_DEFAULT`.

---

And rather too much digging in the debugger leads me to suggest

`@JsonSerialize(using = FlagSetSerializer.class, include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)`

Which seems to pass your tests.

The *problem* seems to be in `JacksonAnnotationInspector#findSerializationInclusion`, which first looks for a `@JsonInclude` attribute on the property, and when it fails to find that, it looks for a `@JsonSerialize` annotation. `@JsonSerialize` includes a deprecated `include` property, which has a default value of `ALWAYS`.

I've not looked into it too deeply, but I suspect a deprecation/refactor managed to slice off some functionality. C'est la vie.

Comment: There is no method with that signature on `JsonSerializer`.  Also, I'm asking about `NON_DEFAULT`, not `NON_EMPTY`.

Comment: Thanks for note on NON_EMPTY vs. NON_DEFAULT.  I've edited the question to fix the mistake in the question.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using? You may want to look at `public boolean isEmpty(T value)`. But all of this may not matter, if you're actually looking for handling of NON_DEFAULT.

Comment: Yes.  I am actually looking at `NON_DEFAULT`, as I've corrected the question to say.

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution and some analysis around why it's problem in your specific version of the library