# Jackson 2: Ignore transient field only when serialising

Tags: java, serialization, jackson2

I'm using Jackson v2 in a JAX-RS app, and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible
to configure "ObjectMapper" to drop fields with transient modifier, but only during serialisation.

Here's a DTO to illustrate my use case (getters & setters omitted)

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private transient String password;
}
```

With the above DTO in mind, I would like to have an object mapper that drops
the password field when serialising, and includes it during deserialisation.

The only thing I could find regarding transient is:

```
MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER
```

But that config isn't relevant to my requirements.

P.S - No annotation are to be used, as the DTO's are not to be coupled to any library, plus
I don't necessarily have control over them.

Comment: I don't understand, if you don't serialize attribute A, what would be deserialized for A, if you include it then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184389/jackson-serialiser-ignore-field-at-serialisation-time - the use case I'm referring to is the the same in that thread (7 years ago).

I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve annotations.

Comment: What you describe doesn't sound anything like the linked question. The accepted answer there doesn't use annotiations for serialization/deserialization. The annotations there are `@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings` and `@Test`. And you didn't answer my question.

Comment: When I'm saying is that an incoming JSON with the fields email, and password should be constructed into an an instance of User, with its email & password populated — When converting the instance of User back to JSON, I would like transient fields to be left out. (The same behaviour should apply to any type not just user.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know, looks like `transient` attribute modifier plus `PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER` just does it. Deserialization is straight forward. There's some [fuss with the transient marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486787/jackson-with-json-unrecognized-field-not-marked-as-ignorable) during serialization, though. You need to provide getters for the fields, otherwise you'll be stuck with an exception "Unrecognized field ... not marked as ignorable".

Reacting to additional requirements I added a version using jackson mixins. Note that the mixin version produces json with an empty password field, while the PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER version produces no field at all.

**PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER version**

```java
public class SerializeDeserializeAttributes {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> c) throws IOException {
    synchronized (mapper) {
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, false);
        return mapper.readValue(json, c);
    }
}

public String toJson(Object o) throws JsonProcessingException {
    synchronized (mapper) {
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, true);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
    }
}

    private static final String jsonFull = "{\"name\":\"A\",\"email\":\"a@a\",\"password\":\"a\",\"width\":1,\"height\":1}";
    private static final String jsonPartial = "{\"name\":\"A\",\"email\":\"a@a\",\"width\":1,\"height\":1}";
    private static final User user = new User("A", "a@a", "a", 1, 1);

    @Test
    public void serializeDeserialize() throws IOException {
        assertEquals(user, fromJson(jsonFull, User.class));
        assertEquals(jsonPartial, toJson(user));
        assertEquals(user, fromJson(jsonFull, User.class));
        assertEquals(jsonPartial, toJson(user));
    }
}
```

**Mixin version**

```java
public class SerializeDeserializeAttributesMixin {

    public abstract class UserMixin {
        @JsonSerialize(using = PwdSerializer.class)
        transient String password;
    }

    static class PwdSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {

        public PwdSerializer() {
            this(String.class);
        }

        private PwdSerializer(Class<String> t) {
            super(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(String s, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
            jg.writeString("");
        }
    }

    private static final String jsonFull = "{\"name\":\"A\",\"email\":\"a@a\",\"password\":\"a\",\"width\":1,\"height\":1}";
    private static final String jsonPartialMixin = "{\"name\":\"A\",\"email\":\"a@a\",\"password\":\"\",\"width\":1,\"height\":1}";
    private static final User user = new User("A", "a@a", "a", 1, 1);
    private static final ObjectMapper mapperMixin = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        mapperMixin.addMixIn(User.class, UserMixin.class);
    }


    @Test
    public void serializeDeserializeUsingMixin() throws IOException {
        assertEquals(user, mapperMixin.readValue(jsonFull, User.class));
        assertEquals(jsonPartialMixin, mapperMixin.writeValueAsString(user));
    }

}
```

That's the User class.

```java
class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private transient String password;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public User() {
    }

    User(String name, String email, String password, int width, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Float.compare(user.width, width) == 0 &&
                Float.compare(user.height, height) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(name, user.name) &&
                Objects.equals(email, user.email) &&
                Objects.equals(password, user.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, email, password, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", width=" + width +
                ", height=" + height +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason the posted code works, is the fact that "fromJson" method is not re-using the same objectMapper instance — I'm afraid creating more than a single instance it a no-op for me.

Comment: architects ‍♂️. I think I'll just use mixins. I cann't mark this is an accepted answer, given that there its not the one I think is right. 

If you'll change your post to include mixins, I'll accept that.

Comment: I guess this does answer the question - But not quite thread safe :)
Either way, its still not vary viable when combined with JAX-RS & a ContextResolver provider. I'll accept this since my question didn't mention the mentioned requirements.

Comment: I added a jackson mixin version.